# Passing a combobox value to the other combobox

Tags: javascript

I have two combo-box:

```
<select ID="combobox1"></select>
<select ID="combobox2" onChange="get_function(this, #combobox1)"></select>
```

What I want to do is, passing the value chosen on the combobox1 to the combobox2 and call the Javascript function:

```
function get_function(combobox1, combobox2)
{
var code1 = combobox1.value;
var code2 = combobox2.value;
if (!code1) return;
if (!code2) return;
alert(code1 + '-' + code2);
}
```

I have tried that code but it doesn't work. How can I do that?

---

**UPDATE**

The problem solved by:

```
<select ID="combobox1"></select>
<select ID="combobox2" onChange="get_function(this, "combobox1")"></select>

function get_function(combobox1, combobox2)
{
var code1 = combobox1.value;
var code2 = document.getElementById(combobox2);
if (!code1) return;
if (!code2) return;
alert(code1 + '-' + code2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select ID="combobox1"></select>
<select ID="combobox2" onChange="get_function(this, "combobox1")"></select>

function get_function(combobox1, combobox2)
{
  var code1 = combobox1.value;
  var code2 = document.getElementById(combobox2);
  if (!code1) return;
  if (!code2) return;
  alert(code1 + '-' + code2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest (if you must use in-line JavaScript):

```
function get_function(combobox1, combobox2) {

    var code1 = document.getElementById(combobox1).value,
        code2 = combobox2.value;

    if (!code1 || !code2) {
        return false;
    }

    else {
        alert(code1 + '-' + code2);
    }

}
```

And call that function like so:

```
<select id="combobox1"></select>
<select id="combobox2" onchange="get_function('combobox1', this)"></select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cRYmN/).

In your original HTML you were calling the function with the parameters in the wrong order, and with an unquoted string for the second parameter (which was the `id` of the first element). Also, you weren't, so far as I could tell, trying to get a reference to the relevant DOM node (the element *itself*) using that `id`, you were simply using the `id` (an unquoted string, and therefore interpreted as a non-existent global variable) directly. Which could never work.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work. I separated the Javascript from the html. Does the same way applied?

Comment: And you'd like me to guess exactly how you separated your JavaScript from the HTML? Does the posted demo work? Because I answered the question that was asked, not the question that you seem to have turned it into since asking.

Answer (score 0):

***[The demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/fxcdb/)***

```
function get_function(el, to_el_id) {
  var to_el = document.getElementById(to_el_id);
    if (to_el) {
        to_el.value = el.value;
    }
}​
```

Comment: So what is your expected result?

Comment: In the function `to_el.value` is the combobox1's value, check the demo plz.